# Append a zero to the left of a decimal number for money?

Tags: php, numbers, decimal, currency

I am trying to display money numbers to users in a readable format.

At the moment the output is like so:

> £ .70

I would like to make this

> £ 0.70

As it is more readable and there is less chance it would get mistaken for £70

I have tried using money format

```
$number = money_format("#1", $number);
```

But I have been unsuccesfull in getting the output I desire.

I then used number_format but that only seems to work with the number itself and not how its displayed i.e. rounding number to Nth decimal place.

I have thought about doing string manipulation like so.

```
if ($number < 1)
$number  = "0" . $number
```

However I am hoping SO know a better way to achieve this rather than string manipulation.

Thanks

Comment: [`echo money_format('%1n', .70);`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8U6YRV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo number_format(.44, 2, ',', ' ');
```

will give you

0,44

Answer (score 1):

check this live demo

```
<?php

echo number_format(.70, 2, '.', ' ');

?>
```

http://codepad.org/XGMAfqgR

check number_Format parameter from here...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#refsect1-function.number-format-parameters